# TYPO3, tt_news not allowing more than one category selected

Tags: php, content-management-system, extension-methods, tt-news, typo3-4.5

I've got a strange "bug" in one of my TYPO3 website.
I've got tt_news installed and have 5 categories in a storage folder.

[image: Categories in the storage folder]

When I **add or edit** a news, I'm able to select my categories, but if I select more than one, a orange warning appears next to the category field and tell me that "a required field

[image: Warning from TYPO3 in the backend]

```
TYPO3   : 4.5.30 
tt_news : 3.4.0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this bug report (and suggestions) http://forge.typo3.org/issues/44274

Comment: Yep but here the news record is already saved and then edited to add more categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the TCA configuration of your news category field.

Go to Admin Tools -> Configuration (in your backend), choose $TCA from select menu on top of the module.

Open the node tt_news/columns/category/config and check the value for maxitems. If it is only 1, the TYPO3 behaviour is correct and you need to find out where you get this setting from, maybe from a setting in typo3conf/extTables.php or from an extension extending tt_news. Please double-check and report back.